# What is Mapzen QPS on reverse Geocoding

Tags: reverse-geocoding, mapzen

Doing some reverse geocoding for an application I am developping, but my qps seems capped at 1 qps.

Is this a hard limit, or is there a way to circumvent that?

I can't find any information on Mapzen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapzen had a 10 QPS.

OpenCage for which we are now migrating to has 10, 12 or 15 depending on Plan. They provide a daily 2,5k request/day for free at 1QPS.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't find any information on Mapzen

https://mapzen.com/blog/migration/

**Note** Mapzen will cease operations at the end of January 2018, and its hosted APIs and all related support and services will turn off on February 1, 2018.

The next best thing is [Pelias](http://pelias.io/)

Comment: Yes, we are going with OpenCage Data its the closest thing for us implementation was easy.